# How to allow MediaWiki logged user to edit Common.css?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to allow the logged user to edit MediaWiki/Common.css without adding them to the sysop group.

I understand that this will allow user to change it to harful ways but it is a closed wiki so that is not a problem.

Any solution is acceptable even changing php code :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a new group, add give it "editinterface" privilege. In LocalSettings.php it's done like this:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['mynewgroup']['editinterface'] = true;
```

Then add the user to you new group.

Or if you want to give that right to all logged-in users, do it like this:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['editinterface'] = true;
// user is the default group for all logged-in users
```

For details see [MediaWiki manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights).

Answer (score 0):

Probably safer to use;

```
$wgAllowUserCss = true;
```

[See Mediawiki Manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowUserCss) for the complete details.

*"When enabled, users are able to make personalised customisations over and above the normal choice of skins within the 'preferences' display."*

A similar setting is available for Javascript.